# Receive MQTT messages on React-Native Expo

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo, mqtt

I've tried the following libraries :

```
react-native-native-mqtt
react-native-mqtt
react_native_mqtt
sp-react-native-mqtt
```

Most of them gave me the same Error :

```
null is not an object (evaluating 'Mqtt.createClient')
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:293:29 in invoke
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:154:27 in invoke
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:189:16 in PromiseImpl$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:45:6 in tryCallTwo
- node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:200:22 in doResolve
- node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:66:11 in Promise
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:188:15 in callInvokeWithMethodAndArg
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:211:38 in enqueue
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:238:8 in exports.async
.... its pretty long and probably says nothing of value.
```

The ones that didn't give me this error; gave me errors about sockets and buffers, almost as if it was trying to run it over web sockets.

What am I doing wrong here?

Is it even possible to get MQTT messages on android react-native?

Is Expo the problem?

Comment: I use this package and it works in my setting: https://github.com/rh389/react-native-paho-mqtt

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have moved on to push notifications for getting these alerts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. An expo Project and fear of ejecting from Expo.

***My actual solution starts from here!***

After a lot of research, I found this module.
[Eclipse Paho MQTT Client for JS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/paho-mqtt)

`npm i paho-mqtt`

Expo Snack Examples:

https://snack.expo.dev/@rizwanamjad/mqtt

https://snack.expo.dev/@eseg/mqtt